# Here is what i am trying to achieve with my Javascirpt, Sorry I'm a newbie at Javascript

Tags: javascript

Sorry i am new to javascirpt been trying to achieve the result on the image attached. Kindly help out with solution applicable.

[Here is what i want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHhai.png)

Here is my HTML CODE:

```
<div class="col p-5">
              <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img src="./img/connecting-to-go-of-elijah.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title text-center">Connecting to God of Elijah</h5>
                  <p class="card-text text-center">Come and experience worship, word encounter, salvation, prayers, deliverance & prophetic declaration.</p>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center"><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">WATCH SERMON</a></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center pt-3">
                      <a href="#" ><img src="./img/film-solid.svg" width="10%" height="auto" class="p-1"/></a>
                      <a href="#" ><img src="./img/headphones-simple-solid.svg" width="10%" height="auto" class="p-1"/></a>
                      <a href="#" ><img src="./img/download-solid.svg" width="10%" height="auto" class="p-1"/></a>
                      <a href="#" ><img src="./img/book-solid.svg" width="10%" height="auto" class="p-1"/></a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Here is my Javascript code

```
function mFeeds()
{
    let headers = new Headers();

    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');

    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://mfeeder.herokuapp.com/feed');
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');

    var requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    redirect: 'follow',
    headers: headers
    };

    fetch("https://mfeeder.herokuapp.com/feed", requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(result => {
        let mResults = JSON.parse(result)
        for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            mTitle = mResults.feeds[i].text
            mDescription = mResults.feeds[i].description
            mLink = mResults.feeds[i].link

            console.log(mTitle, mDescription, mLink)
        }
        

    })
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));

}
```

How do i populate the result mTitle, mDescirption, mLink from my javascript to my HTML page?

Comment: What have you tried? Did you look up similar answers?

Comment: Please use an appropriate title (yours means nothing), don't use link to external resources, insert the images in the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing HTML element text with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58296261/changing-html-element-text-with-javascript)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Sadly your question does not meet the community guidelines. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), visit [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and make it a [minmal, reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best way to achieve this is to create elements inside of your for loop and add them to your container that holds all of the cards.
The process is:
1 - Create a variable to hold the container;
2 - Fetch your data;
3 - Interact and send the element to the function responsible for creating the card;
4 - Append this element to the container.

```js
function myCard(article) {
            return `
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img src="${article.link}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title text-center">${article.text}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text text-center">${article.description}</p>
                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center"><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">WATCH SERMON</a></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center pt-3">
                        <a href="#" ><img src="./img/film-solid.svg" width="10%" height="auto" class="p-1"/></a>
                        <a href="#" ><img src="./img/headphones-simple-solid.svg" width="10%" height="auto" class="p-1"/></a>
                        <a href="#" ><img src="./img/download-solid.svg" width="10%" height="auto" class="p-1"/></a>
                        <a href="#" ><img src="./img/book-solid.svg" width="10%" height="auto" class="p-1"/></a>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            `
        }

        (function mFeeds()
        {
            // This is the container that holds all cards
            const container = document.querySelector('#card-main-container')
            let headers = new Headers();

            headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');

            headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://mfeeder.herokuapp.com/feed');
            headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');

            var requestOptions = {
            method: 'GET',
            redirect: 'follow',
            headers: headers
            };

            fetch("https://mfeeder.herokuapp.com/feed", requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(result => {
                let mResults = JSON.parse(result)
                //console.log(mResults)
                mResults.feeds.forEach(element => {
                    //console.log(element)
                    let parser = new DOMParser();
                    const theCard = parser.parseFromString(myCard(element), 'text/html');
                    container.appendChild(theCard.firstChild)
                });

                for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                    mTitle = mResults.feeds[i].text
                    mDescription = mResults.feeds[i].description
                    mLink = mResults.feeds[i].link

                    //console.log(mTitle, mDescription, mLink)
                }
                

            })
            .catch(error => console.log('error', error));

        })()
```

```html
  <div class="col p-5" id="card-main-container">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function mFeeds() {
  let headers = new Headers();

  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');

  headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://mfeeder.herokuapp.com/feed');
  headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');

  var requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    redirect: 'follow',
    headers: headers
  };

  fetch("https://mfeeder.herokuapp.com/feed", requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(result => {
      let mResults = JSON.parse(result)
      for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        mTitle = mResults.feeds[i].text
        mDescription = mResults.feeds[i].description
        mLink = mResults.feeds[i].link

        //console.log(mTitle, mDescription, mLink)
        document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = mTitle
        document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = mDescription
        document.getElementById("url-link").href = mLink
      }


    })
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));

}
mFeeds()
```

```html
<div class="col p-5">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img src="./img/connecting-to-go-of-elijah.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title text-center" id="title"></h5>
            <p class="card-text text-center" id="description">Come and experience worship, word encounter, salvation, prayers, deliverance & prophetic declaration.</p>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-12 text-center"><a id="url-link" href="#" class="btn btn-danger">WATCH SERMON</a></div>
              <div class="col-lg-12 text-center pt-3">
                <a href="#"><img src="./img/film-solid.svg" width="10%" height="auto" class="p-1" /></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="./img/headphones-simple-solid.svg" width="10%" height="auto" class="p-1" /></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="./img/download-solid.svg" width="10%" height="auto" class="p-1" /></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="./img/book-solid.svg" width="10%" height="auto" class="p-1" /></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Try this, you have to access the html tags with id and change the innerHTML or link. Although your logic has to be updated as your loop runs over all the items and sets the last item as HTML display values